# Query incremental number Mysql Primary Key

Tags: mysql, navicat

I'm having a trouble on how can I add a column before `column1` which is `ID` primary key autoincrement  in Navicat sql query.The expected output should automatically increment the number based on the total number selected query

Current data

```
 column1    column2    column3

 sample    sample     sample2
 sample    sample3    sample4
```

I want to add primary key column autoincrement before column1 which is id using select query based on number of data from the other column.

*expected output*

```
 id    column1   column2  column3
  1    sample   sample   sample2
  2    sample   sample4  sample5
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL2EZ.png)

```
SELECT  sc.id as b2_id,app.covid_id,app.payroll_batch,app.paid_by,app.date_receive,app.remarks,app.eligible,app.amount,app.amount_paid,app.amount_unpaid  
FROM `app_person` as app 
LEFT JOIN b2_sac_numbers AS sc ON sc.sac_number = app.covid_id
```

*What I've tried *

First

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) +1) as id, 
       sc.id as b2_id,app.covid_id,app.payroll_batch,app.paid_by,app.date_receive,app.remarks,app.eligible,app.amount,app.amount_paid,app.amount_unpaid  
FROM `app_person` as app 
LEFT JOIN b2_sac_numbers AS sc ON sc.sac_number = app.covid_id
```

Second

```
SELECT @rownum :=@rownum+1 as id, 
       sc.id as b2_id,app.covid_id,app.payroll_batch,app.paid_by,app.date_receive,app.remarks,app.eligible,app.amount,app.amount_paid,app.amount_unpaid  
FROM `app_person` as app 
LEFT JOIN b2_sac_numbers AS sc ON sc.sac_number = app.covid_id
```

But it seems the result is not the expected result, Is there anyway how to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a _minimal_ sample input data directly _in the question_.  Do not include image links.  Then, also include the expected output and explain the logic.  Most likely, what you really want here is a proper auto increment column, or maybe just use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I've updated my answer above, I just want to add Id in the first column which is incremental, The expected output it should automatically increment the number based on the total number selected

Comment: ...and which column(s) provide the _ordering_ for this new sequence column?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  thanks for your response the id column,I've updated again my example above

Comment: Please add a proper `ORDER BY` clause to your queries, to make obvious the ordering you want here.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen this is just dummy example queries . I just want to know if there's any way to add  ID  before of my queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is there anyway wothout using ` ROW_NUMBER() OVER ` ? I mean so that I will not installed another mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "second" is close to the solution. You missed 3 points:

1. Variable was not initialized
2. No rows ordering (ORDER BY)
3. The row source for this type of enumerating query must use only one table

The solution may be:

```sql
SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 as id, 
       b2_id, covid_id, payroll_batch, paid_by, date_receive, 
       remarks, eligible, amount, amount_paid, amount_unpaid
FROM ( SELECT sc.id as b2_id, app.covid_id, app.payroll_batch, app.paid_by,
              app.date_receive, app.remarks, app.eligible, app.amount, 
              app.amount_paid, app.amount_unpaid  
       FROM `app_person` as app 
       LEFT JOIN b2_sac_numbers AS sc ON sc.sac_number = app.covid_id ) AS total_data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) init_variable
ORDER BY {some expression of columns which provides rows uniqueness}
```

PS. Think - do you really need in LEFT joining? maybe INNER is enough?